# Error while using "python manage.py runserver"

Tags: python, django, git

I am getting the following error. I had previously merged a branch but without success. I then used git reset to go back to a previous commit. After that, I tried to run my project but got the following error. Any help is appreciated.

(oldenv) C:\New folder\Downloads\TECHTUREPS2\bimscoper-rest-api>python manage.py runserver

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

  File "C:\New folder\Downloads\TECHTUREPS2\oldenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()

  File "C:\New folder\Downloads\TECHTUREPS2\oldenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 308, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS

  File "C:\New folder\Downloads\TECHTUREPS2\oldenv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)

  File "C:\New folder\Downloads\TECHTUREPS2\oldenv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)

  File "C:\New folder\Downloads\TECHTUREPS2\oldenv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)

  File "C:\New folder\Softwares\Python 2.7\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)

  File "C:\New folder\Downloads\TECHTUREPS2\bimscoper-rest-api\bimscoper\settings\dev\dev.py", line 9
    <<<<<<< HEAD
     ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: check line 9 in C:\New folder\Downloads\TECHTUREPS2\bimscoper-rest-api\bimscoper\settings\dev\dev.py, looks like the reset left some git-merging-leftovers there (concluded from the last couple of lines in the error trace)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+HEAD+marks

Answer (score -1):

I happened due to changes in the manage.py file ..simply create an empty project and tries to paste all your contents into a new project and migrate them all .
It will work.